# Set google credentials from database, offline

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a big problem with getting google credentials offline. I don't want to use file for storing credentials, because I will have them in database, for each user separately. How to set google credentials from saved values - let's say, I have refresh token in my database. How to set this refresh token from offline?

```
    ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets();
          secrets.ClientId = "4-jq0b0m51ffsdfsdfwwerwr4214i.apps.googleusercontent.com";
          secrets.ClientSecret = "aRfssssseetiFSPZfffDs";

          string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };

//Here is the problem - this method always forces user to get new token online
          UserCredential credential1 = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                secrets,
                      Scopes,
                      "user",
                      CancellationToken.None, new CustomDataStore()).Result;


public class CustomDataStore : IDataStore
{
//other methods omitted, they are not relevant for the question
    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
      //I guess this is the point where I would like to return refresh token from database
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task StoreAsync<TokenResponse>(string key, TokenResponse value)
    {
//I can save token at this point in the database, that's ok - but how to get token from DB?
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to know which use the refreshtoken is associated with and store the userId also along with the refreshtoken in database. You can retrieve the token from the database based the userID next time.

Comment: Take a look on this [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient), does it help you?